# is it possible to create a dll with /MT flag? if yes how to create OpenSSL dlls with /MT flags in windows

Tags: visual-c++, openssl, msdn

We have an application built with /MT flag currently we are upgrading our application from another SSL to OpenSSL. OpenSSL by default built with /MD flag but my application build with /MT so application crashes in OpenSSL.
is it possible to create a dll with /MT flag, if yes then how to create OpenSSL shared libraries with /MT flag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -static option to the opensll configure script.  That will create static libraries using /MT you can link to (i.e. no dll's).

If you are using pre-built libraries you will have to switch to compiling openssl yourself.

You need to follow the INSTALL / NOTES.WIN instructions for the openssl compiling requirements.

Your configure setup could look something like:

> perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix="myinstalldir" -static --release

Comment: Is there any option to create OPENSSL shared libraries(dll) with /MT flag?

Comment: I would say it's not a good idea to go down that road.  You are forcing the dll instance to have it's own runtime instance.  Your better off either going the fully static routine or the fully openssl dll / dll runtime routine.

Comment: I've never tried to do a static runtime of a openssl dll generation.  I would expect you can't configure it to do that.  If you really want to do it, read the configure instructions to see if it's possible.  If not, run configure for a dll setup and then manually edit the makefile to change the runtime to /MT.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution that seems to works and compile openssl dlls without needs of VC Redistribuables.

For that, call :

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A "--prefix=openssl-1.1.1" --release 
or 
perl Configure VC-WIN32 "--prefix=openssl-1.1.1" --release
```

Then replace in the created makefile

```
/MD per /MT (in CNF_CFLAGS param)
/debug per /release (in LDFLAGS param)
```